# Limit fps in loop c++

Tags: c++, sleep, frame-rate, c++-chrono

I have a simple fps limiter, it work: 
Clock.h

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono; 

class Clock 
{ 
    high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime;
public:
    Clock(); 
    duration<double> restart();
};
```

Clock.cpp

```
#include "Clock.h"

Clock::Clock()
: startTime(high_resolution_clock::now())
{

}

duration<double> Clock::restart()
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration<double> elapsed = now - startTime;
    startTime = now;

    return elapsed;
}
```

main.cpp

```
    duration<double> stepInterval(1.f / 60.f);
    duration<double> deltaTime(0);

    Clock clock;
    while(isRunning)
    {
        deltaTime += clock.restart();
        if(deltaTime > stepInterval)
        {
            std::cout << deltaTime.count() * 1000 << std::endl;
            deltaTime = seconds(0);
        }
    }
```

But in this case CPU has a high load. I tried another solutions with std::this_thread::sleep_for, but they does not work with little interval(like 16 ms). Any idea about implementing std::this_thread::sleep_for?

Comment: You might need to use the operating-system specific high-precision clocks and timers. The "normal" timers used by e.g. `sleep_for` might not have enough resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't use `sleep_for`.  Use `sleep_until` instead.  This will average your drift from the desired frame rate out to zero.  This is done by sleeping *until* the start of the current plus the desired frame duration.
- Use `system_clock` so that your frame rate stays accurate over a long period of time.  No clock is perfect.  But `system_clock` will occasionally be adjusted by small amounts to the correct time.  This will have the impact of your frame rate being true to the desired rate over the length of a movie.  Don't follow this advice if you're concerned about a process with admin privileges adjusting the system clock by gross amounts.  In that case use `steady_clock` instead.
- Create a 1/60 s duration type to eliminate floating point round off error.
- Eliminate conversion constants like `1000` in your code to reduce the possibility of logic errors.
- In your `sleep_until`, wake up a little early and then busy-loop until the desired time.  You'll have to experiment with how much early.  Too early and you burn too much CPU (and battery).  Too little, and `sleep_until` occasionally wakes up too late when the CPU is under a high load.

Taken altogether this might look like:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration>
void
sleep_until(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp - 10us);
    while (tp >= Clock::now())
        ;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    using framerate = duration<int, ratio<1, 60>>;
    auto tp = system_clock::now() + framerate{1};

    while (isRunning)
    {
        // do drawing
        ::sleep_until(tp);
        tp += framerate{1};
    }
}
```

Here's a more detailed sketch of the idea that includes "drawing" the current and average frame rate on each frame.  It uses C++17's `chrono::round` function and this [free, open-source C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for the "drawing".

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <class Clock, class Duration>
void
sleep_until(std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp - 10us);
    while (tp >= Clock::now())
        ;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    using framerate = duration<int, ratio<1, 60>>;
    auto prev = system_clock::now();
    auto next = prev + framerate{1};
    int N = 0;
    system_clock::duration sum{0};

    while (true)
    {
        ::sleep_until(next);
        next += framerate{1};

        // do drawing
        using namespace date;
        auto now = system_clock::now();
        sum += now - prev;
        ++N;
        cerr << "This frame: " << round<milliseconds>(now-prev)
             << "  average: " << round<milliseconds>(sum/N) << '\n';
        prev = now;
    }
}
```

Output for me:

```
...
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 15ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 19ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 17ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 17ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 17ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 18ms  average: 17ms
This frame: 16ms  average: 17ms
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. Can you review your code? It does not work for me, CPU still has a high load

Comment: Sorry, I had the comparison in the busy loop incorrect.  Now fixed.

Comment: Hm, i have different output like `31.774 1.5591 28.7145 16.7661`, do you have any idea how fix it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to measure and report the actual instantaneous and average frame rates.

Comment: Great work! But anyway sometimes i have frame time from 0 to 30 ms, average is 17 ms

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you. It worked well for me (good precision):

````
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
    
int main()
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point prev = 
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point current = 
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    int i = 0; 
    
    while (true) {
    
        current = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
        if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(current - prev).count() >= 16000) {
            prev = current;
            i++;
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
        }  
    
    }  
    
    return 0; 
}
```    ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
````

Comment: i think use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));` is not good idea.